# How can I change partition table without data loss?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I hope that I name it that right. I have a root partition a home partition and swap. All I want is to add a partition for windows. BUT my drive is full so I want to shrink the logical home partition 900gb and then assign the 100 gb to windows ntfs. The problem is that the home partition is under extended and when I shrink it the 100 gb for Windows is under extended too. I cannot get it to primary, always logical. How can i change this without data loss? I do not have external drive to empty my drive.

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x0003ead5

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1   *        2048    39064547    19531250   83  Linux
    /dev/sda2        39065598  1945712084   953323243+   5  Extended
    /dev/sda3      1945712640  1953525139     3906250   82  Linux swap / Solaris
    /dev/sda5        39065600  1740912639   850923520   83  Linux
    /dev/sda6      1740914688  1945710591   102397952    6  FAT16
```

thanks

Comment: Please include an `sudo fdisk -l` in your post.

Comment: y sure. i really want help.

Comment: In MBR, you can only have 4 primary partition. So you have to convert one of your primary partition to logical before adding a new primary partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Gparted.

Well, first of all, delete the 100 gb partition you created.

Then, reduce the size of the extended partition by a 100 gb.

Finally, create a new primary partition in the unallocated space left by the previous step.